# Multiple forms in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to develop a vb programe where i am using List to store data. I want to use all datas saved in that list from another class.

In Class 1, i am trying to include a method that will return my list. And form class 2, i will call that method and get that list.

But code isnt working.

Can anyone plz help. ! ! !

Thanks.

For Example.
 **In class one, Name- Add.vb' My thie method was supposed to return list.**

```
Public Property getList() As List(Of Car)
    Get
        Return CarDetails
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of Car))

    End Set
End Property
```

**and In class 2.**

```
Private addobject As Add
Private details As New List(Of Car)

addobject = New Add()

details = addobject.getList()
```

**But I am not getting the list.**

Comment: Can you show (relevant) bits and pieces of the code, and be a bit more detailed on how it does not work?

Comment: Please *Edit* your post and put your code there.

Comment: How is the `CarDetails` list created (and populated)?

Comment: CarDetails is my LIST, I can get all datas in same class,But my problme is I cant create any methods that will let me to get those datas in another class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the problem you are facing, but the `getlist` in the `Add` class is a property, not a method. This means that you should not have the trailing paranthesis when calling it. You can change your code into this:

```
' create a new instance of Add '
Dim addobject As New Add()
' get the list from the property '
Dim details As List(Of Car) = addobject.getlist
```

Comment: Private details As List(Of Car) = addobject.getlist... This line isnt working. Its saying. "End of statement Expected"....
Thanks

Comment: Assuming that the code is located inside a method, it should be `Dim`, not `Private` (my bad; don't write a lot of VB.NET code, and didn't run the code through a compiler before posting it). Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an external class, or class library to the get the list data, and have both forms call that function.